# How does Beamer work?

Tags: appletv, airplay

I have just bought the Beamer app in order to stream videos from my MacBook to my Apple TV, it works great and I am very happy. Previously I was using the AirPlay feature provided by Apple but it often seemed to reduce the video quality and lag. My question is, how the Beamer app works, considering that the Apple TV is quite closed environment, which does not allow third party apps for now? Additionally, if the app relies on the same technology as the AirPlay why the video quality seems better?

Comment: From [Beamer Features](http://beamer-app.com/features) "_Forget what you know about the limitations of AirPlay on the Mac. Beamer takes care of the details, so you can sit down and enjoy all your videos on Apple TV._"  So, if you're satisfied with it do you really need to know more. :)

Comment: Yeah, I saw that, but I was just wondering how do they do it. I know that it is a commercial app, so I don't expect very specific details, but just the general idea

Answer (score 0):

I've used the app for a while. Much of the limitations in Airplay are from the codec limitations of playing video on air play.

Beamer bundles `ffmpeg` usually here:

```
/Applications/Beamer.app/Contents/Resources/ffmpeg
```

On modern systems, this is fast enough to transcode the video to the proper format that Apple TV can play.

I played a video and the command it ran is as follows:

> /Applications/Beamer.app/Contents/Resources/ffmpeg -hide_banner -nostdin -nostats -loglevel warning --segment-length 5 --segment-offset 0 -i file:/Users/risner/Documents/test.mp4 -f mpegts --segment-iframe-only 0 -c:v copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -map 0:0 -c:a libmp3lame -ac 2 -aq 4 -matrix_encoding dplii -ar 48000 -async 1 -map 0:1 pipe:1

This produces a stream that the Apple TV consumes.